# How to capture click event of Flash Object

Tags: javascript

i have a div which has onclick event... On the Onclick of 1st div it need to call onclick of flash object which is 2nd div..

Is there any thing in java script which captures onclick of flash..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) for flash and Javascript to communicate with one another.

It's pretty strait forward.

To send message from Flash to Javascript, use call

```
ExternalInterface.call("some_js_function",param1,param2, etc);
```

To call a Flash function from Javascript,

1. set a callback in flash

   ExternalInterface.add_addCallback("the_external_name",a_flash_function);
2. call the function with javascript

   document.getElementById('flashobjectid').the_external_name(param1, param2, etc)